# No unique no-arbitrage price when the stock price can remain unchanged

Tags: option-pricing, arbitrage, no-arbitrage-theory, european-options

In a 1-period binomial model, with initial stock price 100, if the stock price is either 50,100, or 150 after 1 period then how can I show there is no longer a unique no-arbitrage price for a European call option with strike price K=150. What would the range of values for this price be that ensure there is no arbitrage?

Comment: How do you have 3 prices in a 1 step binomial model?

Comment: Also, your Call would have payoff of zero in an state, no?